# jquery Ajax not responding?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, json

So I have the following function on a page that is supposed to be calling an asp.net webservice and it appears to be doing so but nothing ever happens on the page. Below is the function below that is the webservice

```
$("#BlogSelectList li a").click(function () {
    var str = ($(this).attr("href")).slice(1, 36)
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '../ws/WebServices.asmx/SetActiveBlog',
        data: '{ActiveBlogID: "' + str + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "post",
        success: function (j) {
            if (j.d == 1) {
                window.location('http://www.msn.com');
            }
            else {
                window.location('http://www.msn2.com');
            }
            alert('heyhi')
        }, error: function (j) {
            alert(':(')
        }

    });

});
```

Here is the webservice, I know it is executing because it is running a stored procedure which is making a log entry successfully with "ssss" but the page literally does nothing when the anchor is clicked it doesnt redirect the page, it doesn't do any alert, nothing.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Sets the ActiveBlog.")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public bool SetActiveBlog(string ActiveBlogID)
{
    DbaseExecSpWithReturnValue Sproc = new DbaseExecSpWithReturnValue();
    Sproc.SetSp("sp_CheckUsernameAvailable");
    Sproc.AddParam(1);
    Sproc.AddParam("Username", SqlDbType.Char, "ssss", 20);
    int RetVal = Sproc.Execute();
    Sproc.Close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked using Firebug or something like that to see if the Ajax completes successfully?

Comment: Check if the variable `j` in your success callback is not null or undefined. I guess it might be possible if there is a json parse error. It would explain why you don't see any alerts, as checking for `j.d` in your if condition would crash your callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location` is not a function you call, it's a property you set:

```
if (j.d == 1) {
    window.location = 'http://www.msn.com';
}
```

etc.

Comment: argh you're so right.  I had it as a property but then didn't have the webservice registered, so I changed it to a function thinking I had it wrong, forgot then registered the webservice and forgot to change that back!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is because you are calling `window.location()` instead of setting `window.location.href = 'someUrl'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#BlogSelectList li a").click(function () {
    var str = $(this).attr("href").slice(1, 36);
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '../ws/WebServices.asmx/SetActiveBlog',
        data: '{ActiveBlogID: "' + str + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "post",
        success: function (j) {
            if (j.d == 1) {
                window.location = 'http://www.msn.com';
            }
            else {
                window.location = 'http://www.msn2.com';
            }
            alert('heyhi');
        }, error: function (j) {
            alert(':(');
        }

    });

});
```